# Jest-dom give the error "TypeError: expect(...).toHaveStyle is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, styled-components, react-testing-library, jest-dom

I'm trying to use jest-dom to test a component's styles, and I'm having the error:

```
"TypeError: expect(...).toHaveStyle is not a function"
```

My component is a simple link with styled-components:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const Link = styled.a`
  color: #fff;
`
```

In my test I'm doing:

```
describe('Link', () => {
  it('should display color on the link', () => {
    render(<Link href="/x">Test</Link>)
  }

  expect(screen.getByRole('link', { name: /test/i })).toHaveStyle({ color: '#fff' })
}
```

I created a settings file (jest.config.js) with:

```
module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/.jest/setup.js'],
}
```

At the root of the project I created the .jest / setup.js file and imported the js-dom:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
```

Comment: Facing the same issue, import '@testing-library/jest-dom' worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Since `@testing-library/dom` v5.0.0, there are some breaking changes [compare/v4.2.4...v5.0.0](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/compare/v4.2.4...v5.0.0)

Before v5.0.0, you should use `import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';`

Since v5.0.0, you should use `import '@testing-library/jest-dom';`

You didn't add the matchers for `expect` correctly. That's the reason you get the error.

Comment: Importing `"@testing-library/jest-dom"` in the beginning of the test file worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

From https://testing-library.com/docs/svelte-testing-library/setup/

> 6.2 Add the following to your Jest configuration in package.json

```
{
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"]
}
```

You could add it to your `jest.config.js` since you already have that, rather than `package.json`.

Comment: is that not the same thing as specifying a `setupTest.{js|ts}` file as the value for `setupFilesAfterEnv`?

Answer (score 2):

you can try this :

```
import { toHaveStyle } from '@testing-library/jest-dom'
expect.extend({ toHaveStyle })
```

it works for me.

Comment: I get:

 TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object
        at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)

Answer (score 1):

install jest-styled-components

```
npm i -D install jest-styled-components
```

then use `.toHaveStyleRule`

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-testing-library';
import Button from '../Button';

import 'jest-styled-components';

describe('<Button />', () => {
  it('should render text', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<Button text="Button" />);
    expect(getByText('Button')).not.toBeNull();
  });

  it('should have correct style with background color', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<Button text="Button" color="#fff" />);
    expect(getByText('Button')).toHaveStyleRule('background', '#fff');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following versions in your package:

```
"dependencies": {
 "@types/styled-components": "5.9.1",
 "styled-components": "^5.2.0"
```

},

and import this package into your test file:

`import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'`

Comment: How does importing styled-components have an impact on jest-dom?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from this [link](https://morioh.com/p/b0af67a86107)

To be short:

1. Run: `npm install --save-dev @testing-library/jest-native`
2. Add: `import '@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect'` to your test file
3. Add: `import { toHaveStyle } from '@testing-library/jest-native/dist/to-have-style'`
4. Add: `expect.extend({toHaveStyle})`
5. Finally, you have the `toHaveStyle` for your expect

Sample code:

```
/**
 * @format
 */

import 'react-native';
import '@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';

import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import { toHaveStyle } from '@testing-library/jest-native/dist/to-have-style';

expect.extend({toHaveStyle})

it('renders correctly', () => {
    render(<App/>);

    const text = screen.getByTestId('Sample Text')
    expect(text).not.toBeNull();

    const button = screen.getByTestId('Sample Button')
    expect(button).not.toBeNull();
    expect(button).toHaveStyle({
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    })
});
```